# Rails - MVC explanation of how to use has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a rails beginner and I am having trouble understanding how to use the MVC for a many-many relationship. All of the resources I can find, don't explain how to use the has_many through association in a MVC context, they always use the console to create the objects.

Overview of what I am trying to do:

Library system where there are many users and many books, each user can checkout multiple books, and a book can be checked out by many users.

Here is what I have:

1. Created a `Books` scaffold for CRUD operations
2. Created a `Users` model using devise
3. Created a 3rd model `Checkouts` to link `Books` and `Users` in a `has_many through:` association

What I need help with:

1. Should I also create a `Checkouts` scaffold for CRUD operations? because I need to create/update/destroy links between books/users when they checkout/return books in a MVC context? How would this work as the only experience I have with controller is the one created through the `Books` scaffold, which references books as `@books`, would the `Checkouts` controller be able to identify which `Book` and `User` object I am attempting to create a link for or how does this work???????
2. If `Checkouts` does not need to be a scaffold for CRUD operations, how do I create functions in the controller to reference a `book` and `user` object and insert them into the database? As well as make it a usable route for the view?

PLEASE DO NOT GIVE ME RAW LINKS WITHOUT EXPLANATION, I have read a bunch of rails documentation and watched hundreds of "tutorials" but none of them explain it in a practical MVC usage.

Comment: The answer you provided is really good and helps solve most of my problem. Except for a small thing: `@book.checkouts.build(user_id: id_of_user)`. Is the checkout.builds method built in? because in the tutorials I've watched where they use the console, they simply create `obj = new Checkouts(user_id, book_id)` and then obj.save it, even though your explanation makes sense, I'm just wondering where the `.build` method came from.

Comment: The other issue would be how do I create these functions in the controller and "export"? them as routes? I've tried adding my own functions in the controller file but it doesn't generate new routes for me to link the functions.

Additionally, since users was created using devise, there is no user_controller, if I need to grab data like @user.books, would I need to create a controller for users? would there be any problems with overlapping whatever devise has generated

Comment: See the updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely informative answer, I'll try it out and hope I understood it well enough to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need to create CRUD for `Checkouts`, all you need is the `Checkout` model. Rails uses the associations (has_many, belongs_to, etc) to create the sort of links between models. Think of these associations as Rails connecting the data in your DB based on foreign keys. In your case `Checkouts` is what will link your `Users` and `Books` data. If you look at the relation in your code, your models will look something like the following:

checkout.rb

```
class Checkout
  belongs_to :book # Relation to book_id since it is the link table
  belongs_to :user # Relation to user_id
end
```

user.rb

```
class User
  has_many :checkouts # This is your main relation as checkouts table holds the user_id
  has_many :books, through: :checkouts # Since checkout.rb holds the foreign key for books, you can use through to go to it from checkout.rb
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book
  has_many :checkouts
  has_many :users, through: :checkouts
end
```

At high level, in the background the trail goes as:
User `has_many` Checkouts and Checkouts has a relation to books. Now, from User get all Books by going `through` Checkouts.

To get the data, these associations in your `Controller` look like the following:

```
@user = User.find(1) # Find the user you want
@user.books # Get all the books that were checkout by the user
```

As mentioned before, `@user.books` is possible because of the associations declared in the models.

2. Depending on your application, but a simple example. Lets say that you are in the Books module, and in the view, there is a `checkbox` for "Checkout book?". If the checkbox is marked and before you save the entry, you can do `@book.checkouts.build(user_id: id_of_user)`. Notice that you do not need to add the `book_id`, this is because you are building the relation from `@book`, so it is implicit in the code already. Then when you save, you will see the entry in the DB. If you are in Users, you can do the same but in reverse `@user.checkouts.build(book_id: id_of_book)`.

If after, you want to retrieve the users that took the book you can do:

```
@book = Book.find(1) # Find the book you want
@book.users # Get all the users that checkout that book
```

**UPDATE**

1. Yes, `build` is a [built-in method in rails](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/build). Not sure about the tutorial/guides, but for `has_many`, you can do that. And the same way for `belongs_to`, you can do `build_model_name(...)`. The tutorials you saw show you one way, the usual way to create/save to DB. But using the `build` method, it is easier when it is a linktable. [In this documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), you can see all the class methods available with associations in ActiveRecord.
2. I am not sure about the user using device, but you do not need to create routes or functions (depends on application) for the linktable Checkouts. If you have access to the current user from devise you just need to grab that.

Based on you application, I believe your main logic is in Books, so in create/update you can do

```
@book = Book.new(book_params)
@book.checkouts.build(user_id: @current_user.id)
@book.save
```

You do not necessarily need the controller to make the connections, Rails uses the Models for this. Controllers are just the actions.